# How to make Gedit run a custom command when I save a certain type of file?

Tags: gedit

For example, for source code files, I want gedit to lint it when I save it.

The "run lint" part is done, via the External Tools plugin. Now can I make it run automatically everytime I save a source code file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save your file via your external tool running lint. There's a field *Save* with the following options: *Nothing*, *Current document* and *All documents*. Saving is done before the tool is run.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: External Tools Manager (gedit)]
<sub>(source: [gnome.org](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=external-tools-manager-with-gedit-3.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with [a variation on this](https://gist.github.com/amandabee/9070784) -- I want one keyboard shortcut to run a tool that will tidy Python, CSS or HTML, depending on the file type. But if you map <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to an external tool that runs lint if the file type matches, doesn't if it doesn't, and saves at the end no matter what. Something like this:

```
if [ $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_TYPE = "text/x-python" ]; then
    # Run lint
elif [ $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_TYPE = "text/html" ]; then  
    # Run tidy
elif [ $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_TYPE = "text/css" ]; then
    # run csstidy
else 
    cat -
    echo "Type is:" $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_TYPE > /dev/stderr
    echo "so I'm not doing a thing." > /dev/stderr
fi
```

NB. If your external tool is set to replace your document when it runs, you want to add `cat -` to read the original back into gedit so you don't just clobber it. If your output is all going to the Shell Output pane, you won't need that.

Comment: It looks like gedit won't let you remap ctrl-s, but the basic principle holds.